# darknet: ./src/parser.c:315: parse_yolo: Assertion `l.outputs == params.inputs' failed

Tags: deep-learning, training-data, yolo, darknet

I'm trying to train yolo on my own dataset using darknet
I tried yolov2,yolov3 to do so..
I followed this article here https://medium.com/@manivannan_data/how-to-train-multiple-objects-in-yolov2-using-your-own-dataset-2b4fee898f17 ..
but every time i start training I get the same error

```
darknet: ./src/parser.c:315: parse_yolo: Assertion `l.outputs == params.inputs' failed
```

some times I got another similar error but with parse_region Assertion
I tried many solution most of them recommend to fix the number of filters but I can't figure it out, so here's my yolov3.cfg

```
[net]
# Testing
# batch=1
# subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=20
subdivisions=16
width=640
height=640
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 500200
policy=steps
steps=400000,450000
scales=.1,.1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

######################

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=255
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 6,7,8
anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
classes=5
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1


[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 61



[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=255
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 3,4,5
anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
classes=5
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1



[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 36



[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=30
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 0,1,2
anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
classes=5
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1
```

and this my obj.data

```
classes= 5
train  = train.txt  
test  = test.txt  
names = obj.names  
backup = weights/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the convolution layer before each YOLO layer. You only changed the last one out of 3. Please check, there is two other convolutional layer with "filters=255" for 80 classes.